# dada una secuencia de 1 y 0 necesito saber cuantos tramos del mismo número hay, en qué orden, y cuantos elementos contiene cada tramo

Tags: r, libreoffice-calc

Tengo unos registros que me indican para un conjunto de personas si la persona ha usado o no unos servicios en una relación continua de meses. Lo tengo definido como una secuencia de valores binarios 1111000011100111110000. Querría obtener un resultado que me dijera cuantos meses seguidos ha usado los servicios y lo mismo para los meses que no los usó.

En el ejemplo convertido a binario querría obtener 443254. Eso me permitiría saber que esa persona ha tenido relación nosotros 3 veces, y ahora hace 4 meses que no usa los servicios. Y su período más largo con nosotros ha sido de 5 meses y su más corto de 2.

Ah! se me olvidaba que esto lo tengo en una tabla dinámica de Calc pero si hace falta pasarlo a otra cosa, como R, se pasa. Gracias.

Comment: Y qué has intentado para resolver tu problema? Qué error encontraste?

Comment: Era una petición de ayuda/orientación para resolver la necesidad. Todavía no habían aparecido errores porque no sabía como resolver el problema. Gracias

Comment: Bienvenidx a Stack Overflow en español. 
Las preguntas del tipo: "Tengo que hacer esto" sin mostrar el código que has escrito no suelen ser bien recibidas ya que la respuesta será siempre adivinando y no encaja en el formato de preguntas y respuestas del sitio. 
Recomiendo que hagas el [recorrido](https://es.stackoverflow.com/tour) para entender el funcionamiento de SO y ya de paso ganar tu primera medalla. 
Por otro lado, estaría bien que le echaras un vistazo a [Cómo preguntar](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) para que tus preguntas reciban respuesta más rapido y fácil.

Comment: PD. Preguntar sin mostrar que te has esforzado por intentarlo no suele ser bien recibido. Es todo.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
library(stringr)

foo <- "1111000011100111110000"

bar <- sapply(str_extract_all(foo,"([0-1])\\1+")[[1]], nchar)

bar

1111  0000   111    00 11111  0000 
   4     4     3     2     5     4 

paste(bar, collapse = "")
[1] "443254"
```

## Explicación

La idea es usar una regex que extraiga grupos de 1 o 0 seguidos de 1 o 0. Eso hace `"([0-1])\\1+"`, crea un grupo que empieza en 0 0 1 y lo mantiene mientras que el caracter siguiente sea igual al anterior. Lo adapté a partir  de https://www.regextester.com/97975

La función `str_extract_all()` se encarga de pasar la regex por la cadena y produce un vector con cada grupo. `nchar` cuenta cuantos caracteres tiene una cadena y usamos `sapply()` para pasar esa función por cada cadena en el vector. `sapply()` nos regresa un vector con cada conteo por separado, después se puede usar `paste(x, collapse = "")` para generar una sola cadena con todos los números. Quizás el resultado intermedio te resulte más útil.

Seguramente hay alguna aproximación mejor que una regex, pero esta funciona.

Comment: Genial. Buscaba esto.

Answer (score 1):

Con R base

```
cadena <- "1111000011100111110000"

rle(strsplit(cadena, "")[[1]])$lengths

[1] 4 4 3 2 5 4
```

[`rle()`](https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/base/versions/3.6.2/topics/rle) hace todo el trabajo, cuenta las secuencias de valores iguales y obtiene la longitud de cada grupo

Comment: Me parece una solución elegante. Soy nuevo en R y me falta mucho background. Gracias